# GAP checking for symmetric group

Tags: group-theory, computational-mathematics, gap

In GAP one can use
`StructureDescription(G)` to find out that $G$ is isomorphic to (say) $S_{120}.$ ($G$ might be defined by a collection of permutation of $140$ elements). One can also ask `IsSymmetricGroup(G)` which is a lot faster but just returns a boolean, so if the answer is `true`, we don't know if it is isomorphic to $S_{120}$ or $S_{7}.$ Is there some trick to get the degree of the permutation rep? `StructureDescription` is *much* slower.

Comment: isn't there a function that gives you the order of G?

Comment: @Jorge Good point, but I am not sure it helps, effiiency-wise.

Comment: Computing the order is a lot quicker than $\mathtt{StructureDescription}$ (which would have to compute the order first anyway). It would be helpful if you could say what sort of examples you have in mind. $S_{120}$ on $140$ points  would be easy because it would have an orbit of size $120$ with the natural action.

Comment: In fact you can just call $\mathtt{SymmetricDegree}$ on your group after $\mathtt{IsSymmetricGroup}$.

Comment: Results of the comparison of the execution times of different GAP functions:
g:=SymmetricGroup(120);
h:=SymmetricGroup(100);
for k in [1..10^8] do IsSymmetricGroup(g);IsSymmetricGroup(h);od;time;
5890
for k in [1..10^8] do StructureDescription(g);StructureDescription(h);od;time;
9328
for k in [1..10^8] do Order(g);Order(h);od;time;
9766
for k in [1..10^8] do SymmetricDegree(g);SymmetricDegree(h);od;time;
13968

Comment: @IgorRivin See also `IsNaturalSymmetricGroup` (Type `?IsNaturalSymmetricGroup` to see the documentation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted, `StructureDescription` (which is a toy routine for small examples) will perform horribly badly on this question. But there are two special functions for this task:

- `IsNaturalSymmetricGroup` takes a permutation group and checks whether it is the the symmetric group on its `MovedPoints`. (That is, it returns `true` on the group $\langle (4,5,6),(4,5)\rangle$.) The algorithm used will be much faster than even computing the order and should easily work for degrees into the 10000s.
  The degree is then given by `NrMovedPoints`.
- `IsSymmetricGroup` in contrast tests whether a group (of arbitrary representation) is isomorphic to a symmetric group. If so, `SymmetricDegree` will
  return the degree of this symmetric group. The algorithm calculates the order and then a composition series and tests (with special treatment for $n=6$) that the group has a normal subgroup of index 2 isomorphic to $A_n$ (which, apart from $A_8$ can be identified from its order once we know it is simple) on which the group induces an outer automorphism.